# Redux: Why are reducers called twice (beginner)

Tags: redux

why are my reducers called twice? Please find firste the source code and below a screenshot from developer tools.

Code:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const initState = {
    title: "-",
    todos: []
}

function rootReducer(state = initState, action) {
    console.log("rootReducer, state=", state, "rootReducer, action=", action);

    if (action.type === "ADD_TODO") {
        return {
            ...state,
            todos: [...state.todos, action.todo],
        }
    }
    return state;
}

const store = createStore(rootReducer);


store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log("State updated!", store.getState());
});


store.dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TODO', todo: 'Learn Babel' });
```

Developer tools:
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Because you have two actions dispatched - @@redux/INIT and ADD_TODO

Comment: @Brejk This is my whole source code and there is only one command that dispatches an action.

Comment: The first one is dispatched by redux automatically

Answer (score 1):

The first invocation is from createStore(rootReducer) trying to test your reducer for bad patterns.